# How to check timestamp of a text file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp, excel-2003

I'm trying to write a code in Excel 2003 VBA (Windows XP) to find out if outside TXT file has different timestamp, so I can 'import' it if it changed.

Is there any function in VBA that can save me?

Comment: Yup there is :) BTW which timestamp are we talking about? Created Date or Modified Date?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want the modified date. If yes, then see this

```
Debug.Print FileDateTime("C:\Sample.txt")
```

The format of the date and time displayed is based on the locale settings of your system.

**Edit**

Using `FileSystemObject`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = "C:\MyFile.txt"

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    '~~> Created Date
    Debug.Print "Created Date : "; oFS.GetFile(sFile).DateCreated

    '~~> Modified Date
    Debug.Print "Modified Date : "; oFS.GetFile(sFile).Datelastmodified

    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub
```