# Insert new file name in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a macro I recorded for a project that I am working on. There is a new text file that comes weekly (in this example the file name is `HMO04102015.txt`) and I am wondering whether there is a way (maybe an additional macro that I can put into the code) that I can pull the new weekly file name and replace it automatically (maybe like a "pull most recent time stamp" function). The files come on the same day of the week so I know what day they are coming (if that helps at all).

```
Sub textimport()
'
' textimport Macro
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;C:\Users\Employee\Desktop\Test Data\HMO04102015.txt", _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "HMO04102015"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(11, 29, 9, 7, 2, 3, 167, 51, 39, 18)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 27
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Application.GetOpenFilename` to choose the file. See this code

If you want the file with the recent timestamp, then that can be easily [ADDED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823444/how-to-check-timestamp-of-a-text-file-using-vba) as well. You will have to loop through files in a folder using [DIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) and checking for the latest Time Stamp.

```
Sub textimport()
    Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Ret, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, I would probably want to grab the latest file, seeing that multiple files are housed in one folder (e.g. TestFile04102015, TestFile04172015,TestFile04242015). You mentioned that to pick the most recent file in I would need to incorporate the DIR fuction. How would I do that (using the example file name TestFile04242015)? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Will the filename always have the latest time stamp?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, yes the file will have the same name, although each files have a time stamp (mm-dd-yyy) so, for example, one file may be named TestFile04102015 and the next file will be name TestFile04172015. All files are exactly 7 days apart.

Comment: So why not loop through the files and extract 8 number from right of the filename and check which is the latest? I have already given you a link to loop through the file?